# Deserializing with GSON converting java.sql.Date incorrectly

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using GSON to deserialize a JSON string to a java object. The date in the JSON string is of the format:

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```

When the date is read into a java.sql.Date field in my JAVA object, the month always ends up as 01 or january! Very strange.

Here is the code for the JSON String and deserializing with GSON:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String jsonString = "[{\"date\":\"2015-02-14\"},{\"date\":\"2015-03-15\"},{\"date\":\"2015-04-16\"}]";

    Type type = new TypeToken<List<TestObject>>(){}.getType();
    Gson gsonReceiver = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd").create();
    List<TestObject> objectList = gsonReceiver.fromJson(jsonString, type);

    for(int i=0; i < objectList.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("objectList[" + i + "] = " + objectList.get(i).toString());          
    }
}
```

And here is the code for the TestObject:
    public class TestObject {

```
private Date date;

public TestObject(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "TestObject [date=" + date + "]";
}
```

}

If you run this piece of code, the dates in the new object get printed out as:

```
objectList[0] = TestObject [date=2015-01-14]
objectList[1] = TestObject [date=2015-01-15]
objectList[2] = TestObject [date=2015-01-16]
```

Which is just plain weird.

I think I have set the date format like I should - anybody have any idea what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right format is

```
yyyy-MM-dd
```

`mm` stay for minutes. Not months.

Here is the javadoc explaining each letter that can be used in date format functions: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Infact `GSonBuilder` uses the same conventions of `SimpleDateFormat`:

> Note that this pattern must abide by the convention provided by SimpleDateFormat class. See the documentation in SimpleDateFormat for more information on valid date and time patterns.

Comment: Doh! Thanks Davide - that was driving me bonkers! Tom

Comment: If it you find the answer useful and right you can upvote it and select as the right answer using the green flag. Thank you!

Comment: Just waiting the necessary 12 minutes or whatever it tells me!